# How to replace a mongoose object with a different object from find method

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

### Currently I want to replace an object value with a different value from the mongoose `find()` method

This is the first object in an array

```json
[
 {
        "_id": "622763aeb93e4fb805adc167",
        "channel_id": "124729170944",
        "author": "1",
        "id": "213568723968",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-08T14:09:50.871Z",
        "attachments": [],
        "content": "EHHEHHEHEHE",
        "__v": 0
 },
]
```

#### So I want to replace the `author` with a user object. I have a user document I want to replace the author value to, so how do I do that?

### Example Result

```json
[
 {
        "_id": "622763aeb93e4fb805adc167",
        "channel_id": "124729170944",
        "author": {
           "username": "Test Account",
           "id": "1"
        },
        "id": "213568723968",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-08T14:09:50.871Z",
        "attachments": [],
        "content": "EHHEHHEHEHE",
        "__v": 0
 }
]
```

### This is the code I am using right now

```js
  const data = await this.messageModel.find({ channel_id }, null, {
      limit: limit ? limit : 1000,
    });
```

The **schema** for `user`:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema()
export class User extends Document {
  @Prop()
  username: string;

  @Prop()
  status: string;

  @Prop()
  createdAt: string;

  @Prop()
  id: string;

  @Prop()
  email: string;

  @Prop()
  password: string;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

The **schema** for `message`:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type MessageDocument = Message & Document;

interface MessageAttachments {
  url: string;
  name: string;
}

@Schema()
export class Message {
  @Prop()
  content: string;

  @Prop()
  attachments: MessageAttachments[];

  @Prop()
  createdAt: string;

  @Prop()
  id: string;

  @Prop()
  author: string;

  @Prop()
  channel_id: string;
}

export const MessageSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Message);
```

This is how I inject the model

- https://sourceb.in/jP53FPb9aZ

Comment: You are looking for [Mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate).

Comment: @prasad_ Thank you, but I have a hard time understanding the docs. Could you show a little example of how to use it? Also, I edited the post because I provided a wrong object example

Comment: I suggest you also include the schema definitions for _message_ and the _user_ in your question post.

Comment: How are the `author` of messages and the users related?

Comment: @prasad_ The original `author` value is a user id from a user that is stored in the user's model. I want to replace the original value to the user object from the user's model by querying it with the user id.

Comment: You can do this by using the Aggregation [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) - by performing a "join".

Comment: @prasad_ I finally figured it out! Thank you for helping me :)